# Where to save user data (identity, ban, access) and how to check it on every request for API calls?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, authentication, redis, authorization

I have API for book web library and some of them (i think about 40%) need some of user data to check (for actions like book add, tag add, rate and so on):

**Static**

- Identity (id)

**Dynamic (this values can change)**

- Access level(for some api calls it's 10, for another is 20).
- Ban(true or false).
- Tokens for patreon api calls.

How can i make it as simple secure and scalable as possible? What is current trends?

---

For now i know this methods:

1) After login you store all data in DB and set user session in cookies. On request you load data from DB on server side check user session and use DB data to check dynamic values for this api call.

- Pros: simple, scalable
- Cons: DB load (but maybe it's ok?)

2) After login you give user access token with all data (like JWT) and use it on every request, checking on server side with no need for DB requests.

- Pros: simple, scalable, no need for DB calls to check user.
- Cons: no way to update/deny token if dynamic values (ban, trust) was changed (or maybe there is a way?). Patreon tokens i can update if patreon request from server got error.

3) After login you store all data in Redis with expire time if not used and set user session in cookies. On request you load data from Redis on server side, check user session and use this Redis data to check dynamic values for this api call.

- Pros: fast, no need for DB calls for user check.
- Cons: complex, to scale you will need separate shared redis server for user dynamic checks (maybe it's not so much difference if you will just load from db like in example 1?)